# Continue with script after navigating outside of domain PHP

Tags: php

I am using code using a link to add data to an external DB:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://secure.site.com/Import.aspx?name=test&phone=1234567890';

echo "<script>window.location = '". $url . "'</script>";

?>
```

This works as far as placing the data in the external DB.

However, since I don't have access to the script on the other end, I can't control where it leads to once the data feed is complete.

It just dead ends leaving the word 'Success' on a blank page.

Is there a way to get my script to navigate back to a page on my server after it goes 'outside' to the other site?

I have tried redirects, headers, includes, etc but none of that seems to work as once I go out to that link the next line of my code is not read.

Comment: Open external link in a new window, that's it. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp How is this related to php? Or you can make request with php to another server - cURL, or simple `file_get_contents('https://secure.site.com/Import.aspx?name=test&phone=1234567890');`

Comment: Your external db adds records to its database with a GET request and no form of authentication whatsoever? That's just wrong.

Comment: i asked them for credentials, but they control data entry via a unique client ID and a case #.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want to invoke that url, then don't redirect just call it, feed it with the necessary query string. No need to redirect so you'll just stay in your codes.

```
$data = array('name' => 'test', 'phone' => '1234567890');
$query_string = http_build_query($data);

$url = 'https://secure.site.com/Import.aspx?' . $query_string;
$response = trim(file_get_contents($url));

if($response == 'Success') { // if this is indeed the return value of that page
    // do what you have to do next
}
```

Comment: @further_up glad this helped. but just like jeroen has said in the comments, its sad that anyone can just invoke that url without some form of authentication. you might wanna notify the owner of that particular site if you have no control of the codes there